# Logging in Groovy: not able to write logs to file

Tags: logging, groovy, log4j, logback, slf4j

I have a groovy project. I am using `Slf4j` for logging.
I want a log file to be generated. But I am only getting logs in the console. Though the log file is generated with following content, this do not contain the application logs that I have mentioned/am expecting during the course of application run. Here is my `application.log`

```
2016-06-26 02:09:28 DEBUG logging:19 - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4jLoggerProvider
2016-06-26 02:09:28 INFO  Version:17 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.2.Final
2016-06-26 02:09:28 DEBUG DefaultTraversableResolver:70 - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
2016-06-26 02:09:28 DEBUG ValidationXmlParser:91 - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
2016-06-26 02:09:28 DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper:54 - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
2016-06-26 02:09:28 DEBUG ResourceLoaderHelper:60 - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
2016-06-26 02:09:28 DEBUG ValidationXmlParser:98 - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
```

I have the following jars in my classpath:

```
slf4j-api-1.7.12 , jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12-sources.jar , log4j-1.2.16-sources.jar, logstash-logback-encoder-2.4-sources.jar, logback-core-1.1.2-sources.jar, logback-classic-1.1.2-sources.jar.
```

Note that I have tried after removing the last 3 and/or 2nd one.

I am using annotation `@Slf4j` and import `import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j` Then i just do `log.info "INFO LOG"`. I have tried with generating all type of logs here i.e. warn/error/info but nothing is getting written in the file. I have also used `private static final Logger REQUEST_LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExampleLog.class)` with import

```
org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

But nothing seems to be working.

This is my config file `log4j.xml` in resource(added in the classpath)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

    <log4j:configuration debug="true" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
        <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
            <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
            <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender> 
        <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
           <param name="append" value="false" />
           <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
           <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
           <param name="file" value="/Users/user/logs/application.log" />
           <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
                value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
           </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <!--  priority value="warn"/-->
            <level value="DEBUG"></level>
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </root>

    </log4j:configuration>
```

One more behaviour that I am observing is that even if I remove the console appender part, the logs are generating in the console absolutely as expected, but even after trying with lots of permutations and combinations, I am not able to generate logs in file.

Is there any role of `logback` here? Is there anything wrong in the annotation part?